# What is this bug living on the plaster in my home?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

It's a small larva looking creature that pops out of a volcanoe-esque hole in the bathroom. SE United States.[image]

Comment: Sort of looks like a barnacle... but could be the start of a wasp nest if it is on a ceiling. Can you comment on whether it is submerged in water or what sort of surface it is adhered to?

Comment: It's on typical drywall on the wall in my home.

Comment: Opening is about a mm big.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Please don't put new information into the comments, which are only for discussing how to improve the post. Since comments are ephemeral and often overlooked they should not be used for information important to understanding the question. ——— You may also wish to take the [tour] and then consult the [help] pages for additional advice on [ask] effectively on this site. Thank you!